# F# - Extract option from Expr

Tags: f#

Is there a way to extract a parameter from an `Expr`?

An example:

```
let hasStringOption (e:Expr<string option>) =
    let myOption : string option = ..some code to get the string option from e
```

How would I get the `string option` inside the `Expr` and assign it to `myOption`?

Comment: It depends, if you have <@ Some (f x) @>, would you like to evaluate the function call or not? If so, use Eval as mentionned by wmeyer; Otherwise, Stephen's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `string option` represents the expression *return type*, so the expression itself could be arbitrarily complex and requires some kind of evaluation strategy like the PowerPack's as @wmeyer has shown.

But if you actually have a `string option` *expression* you can use the standard library quotation active patterns and reflection to implement your own evaluation strategy (generic option shown here):

```
module P = Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let extract (expr:Expr<'a option>) =
    match expr with
    | P.NewUnionCase (uci, args) ->
        if uci.Name = "Some" then
            match args.Head with
            | P.Value(value, ty) -> Some(value :?> 'a)
        else
            None:('a option)

let example1 = extract <@ None:int option @>
let example2 = extract <@ Some("hello world") @>
```

and indeed, such an approach may be a piece of your own strategy for recursively evaluating arbitrary expressions using reflection and active patterns rather than PowerPack's slow and limited intermediate LINQ strategy.

Comment: thanks for the neat function :) - But.. why do you use `None:('a option)`? Whats the : all about?

Comment: Hi @ebb, you're welcome. The `:('a option)` part of `None:('a option)` is just a type annotation I originally used to help the compiler infer the return type of `extract`. But it turns out to be unnecessary since  the `Some(value :?> 'a)` branch is enough a clue (I wrote the None branch first). On the other hand, `:int option` *is* necessary in order to help the compiler infer the ultimate type of `example1`. But it could also have done by placing the type annotation on example1 itself: `let example1:int option = extract <@ None @>`

Answer (score 3):

With `FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll` referenced you can do:

```
  open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations 
  open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation


  let hasStringOption (e:Expr<string option>) =
      let myOption : string option = e.Eval()
      myOption.IsSome

  printfn "%A" (hasStringOption <@ Some "hello" @>)
  printfn "%A" (hasStringOption <@ None @>)
```

However, reportedly this is quite slow and uses LINQ expressions as an intermediary step.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly (or not), you cannot evaluate F# quotations. The F# PowerPack has a limited ability to compile quotations to LINQ expressions (which can be evaluated).

Comment: I've implemented a custom reflection-based quotation evaluator which is now part of Unquote, http://code.google.com/p/unquote/, as of version 2.0.0. I've measured it to be up to 50 times faster than PowerPack's evaluator, and it supports many more expressions as well.